# How to avoid the last comma while writing an integer array into a text file in python

Tags: python, arrays, file-writing

I need to write an array of integers into a text file, but the formatted solution is adding the comma after each item and I'd like to avoid the last one.

The code looks like this:

```
        with open(name, 'a+') as f:
           line = ['FOO ', description, '|Bar|']
           f.writelines(line)
           f.writelines("%d," % item for item in values)
           f.writelines('\n')
```

Each line starts with a small description of what the array to follow contains, and then a list of integers. New lines are added in the loop as they become available.

The output I get looks something like this:

> FOO description|Bar|274,549,549,824,824,824,824,824,794,765,765,736,736,736,736,736,

And I would like to have it look like this, without the last comma:

> FOO description|Bar|274,549,549,824,824,824,824,824,794,765,765,736,736,736,736,736

I was unable to find a solution that would work with the writelines() and I need to avoid lengthy processing in additional loops.

Comment: convert the string to list by mapping or something then do: obj.rstrip(',') after that write it to the text file as it'll finally need a textfile (string) to write to a file!

Comment: Use `','.join(values)` instead of the formatting?

Comment: @Jon, that's an answer. If you don't want to write it down, I'll take the points. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `join`:

```
f.writelines(",".join(map(str,values)))
```

Note that `values` is first mapped to a list of strings, instead of numbers, with `map`.

Comment: This would work, but I need to keep numbers without converting them to strings

Comment: Content written to a file is always written as a string, you convert it to string yourself with the `%` operator, and the desired output you have at the end of your question is a string. So I must ask: What do you mean?

Comment: That is a good point, for some reason I've been unaware of that transformation. I guess I was looking for a way to actually preserve the original type of the data, but it doesn't seem to be possible with the text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice it with using below example. 
It will always delete last character.

```
line = ['FOO ', description, '|Bar|']
line = line[:-1]
f.writelines(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Slicing is the best approach and works well for every situation atleast in your case.

```
    f.writelines(line[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use print function here.

```
print(*values,sep=',',file=f)
```

If you are using python2 please import print function.

```
from __future__ import print_function
```